# How to make many to many relationship with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, many-to-many

i have a database and there is Movie Table and Country table and also i made a Movie_Country table for many to many relationship

but when i select my database and generate an entity model in my .net project this relationship returns to one to many for Movie and Movie_Country and also Country and Movie_Country

so i cannot add record to many to many table with code what can i do for generate model with many to many relationship as my database diagram show

[image]
[image: My Many To Many Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Entity framework many to many relationships need to be made with a table with both of the joining foreign keys as a compound primary key and no other properties on the table.

In other words make movieID and countryID your compound primary key and remove movie_country_id from T_Movie_Country and it should work. I also think that the foreign keys will have to be primary keys in their respective tables. So movieID would have to be your primary key in your T_Movie table.